# Magento 2 : Need to add pagebuilder category attribute in admin category page

Tags: magento2, category-attribute

I want to create the category attribute with pagebuilder button. I have tried with below code but its not working. After save the category it is showing wysiwyg editor instead of pagebuilder button.
i have used magento version is 2.4.5-p1 which is upgaded from 2.3. Same code working on fresh magento version 2.4.5-p1.

here is a installData.php

```
/**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function install(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY,
            'pagebuildertopcontent',
            [
                'type' => 'text',
                'label' => 'Top Content',
                'input' => 'textarea',
                'sort_order' => 110,
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'default' => '',
                'group' => 'PageBuilder Content Settings',
                'backend' => ''
            ]
        );
    }
```

Here is a category_form.xml files

```
<field name="pagebuildertopcontent" template="ui/form/field" sortOrder="50" formElement="wysiwyg">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="wysiwygConfigData" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="is_pagebuilder_enabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="pagebuilder_button" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="toggle_button" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="height" xsi:type="string">100px</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <label translate="true">dev</label>
                <notice translate="true">Note: Keyboard shortcut to activate editor help : Alt + 0 (Windows) or &#x2325;0 (MacOS)</notice>
                <dataScope>pagebuildertopcontent</dataScope>
            </settings>
            <formElements>
                <wysiwyg class="Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Category\Form\Element\Wysiwyg">
                    <settings>
                        <rows>8</rows>
                        <wysiwyg>true</wysiwyg>
                    </settings>
                </wysiwyg>
            </formElements>
        </field>
```